# Wrong value from strigsdict file for ru language in en system locale

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have ru/en app and I need to change the language of the app manually.

So, for localization I have a func like this:

```
    func localizedFormat(args : CVarArgType...) -> String  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(Localize.currentLanguage(), ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
    let string = bundle?.localizedStringForKey(self, value: nil, table: nil)
    return withVaList(args) {
        NSString(format: string!, arguments: $0)
        } as String
}
```

From `Localize.currentLanguage()` I always get `ru`.

I also have a `sringsdict` file with plurals. The problem is the following:
when I run simulator with `ru` language - everything works good. But, if I run in `en` - the plurals are taking from the `stringsdict` wrong, because they are taking on `en` plural rules.

So the values are taken from the Russian `stringsdict` but only `one` and `other`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject([Localize.currentLanguage()], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

But this doesn't help.

Why does iOS taking info from the correct `stringsdict` but as it's the `en` app language?

Comment: You write "But, if I run in en - the plurals are taking from the stringsdict wrong, because they are taking on en plural rules." - If you run in `en` it **should** use the `en` plural rules!

Comment: @Mundi I need to change app lang and ignore system settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to change `Bundle path` to localized one to get the correct argument from the `sringsdict` file
2. When creating `String` you need to pass the correct locale to the initializer

Final method will look like this:

```
func localizePlural(key: String, count: UInt) -> String? {
    let language = "ru"
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"), let bundle = Bundle(path: path) else {
        return nil
    }
    let formatString = NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
    let resultString = String(format: formatString, locale: Locale.init(identifier: "ru_RU"), count)
    return resultString
}
```